# ¿Por qué no me deja subir los cambios de mi proyecto a Git Hub?

Tags: github, git-bash

Explico paso a paso lo que hice:
Tenia mi proyecto de `Angular` sin modularizar, venia haciendo los `git add .` , `git commit -m` y los `git push` a `Git Hub` sin problema. Hasta que decidi empezar a modularizar mi proyecto, para no afectar a la versión por posibles errores al modularizar, decidí copiar mi proyecto **"cds-bookstore-new" del disco C** y lo pegué en una carpeta llamada **"lazy-loading" ubicada en escritorio**. Quedando de esta manera:
**desktop/lazy-loading/cds-bookstore-new** y empecé a modularizar y hacer cambios desde esta carpeta (sin subir nada a `git hub`).
Al terminar de modularizar hice lo siguiente:

1. Borré la carpeta **"cds-bookstore-new"** que estaba en el **disco C**.
2. Copié de **desktop** la carpeta **"cds-bookstore-new"** y la pegué en el **disco C**.
3. Despues abrí el `Git Bash` **me ubique en la carpeta cds-bookstore-new del disco C**, y tipie los siguientes comandos:

a) `git add .`
b) `git commit -m 'bla bla bla'`
c) y cuando hice el `git push` dice que los updates fueron rechazados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

d) entonces hice un `git pull` y seguido un `git push` otra vez, pero vuelve a informarme que los updates fueron rechazados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice un `git status` y me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como solucionarlo.

Comment: No puedes hacer push aún porque el pull está incompleto debido a un conflicto. Parece que en lo que tenías en github hay un cambio incompatible con los cambios que has estado haciendo en local. No estoy seguro pero creo que se trata del fichero `frontend/src/app/user/book-detail/book-detail.component.ts`. Aparentemente has borrado ese fichero en github, pero en cambio lo has editado y modificado en la versión local. Debes decidir cuál de los dos cambios (borrarlo o editarlo) es el que vale

Comment: Cuando lo hayas decidido, debes hacer saber tu decisión a git. Si eliges que estaba bien borrarlo, haz `git rm` de ese fichero. Si eliges que en cambio quieres dejarlo con las modificaciones locales, haz `git add` de ese fichero. En cualquier caso después haz `git commit`. Eso terminará el pull que estaba a medias y te permitirá hacer después el `push`.

Comment: Gracias por responder, soy novato con git bash, si quiero dejar el archivo book-detail/book-detail.component.ts con las modificaciones locales, el comando seria asi: git add  frontend/src/app/user/book-detail/book-detail.component.ts  ????

Comment: Sí. También puedes usar `git add -u` sin más en este caso (que añade los ficheros modificados, y en este momento ese es el único). En todo caso verifica después con `git status` que te lo marca como añadido para commit

Comment: hice el git add -u despues el commit y por ultimo el push pero sale este error:

Comment: ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/claudiocds1987/miProyecto.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Y si ahora haces otra vez pull? Porque te está diciendo que sigue habiendo cambios en github que tú no tiens. ¿Has cambiado alguna otra cosa allí? ¿Hay alguien más colaborando en el repo que pueda estar subiendo cambios?

Comment: No, yo solo estoy en este proyecto, no hay colaboradores

Comment: hic eel git pull y muestra esto:  CONFLICT (rename/delete): frontend/src/app/components/user/user.component.spec.ts deleted in 177133d6e2f09d62adb520e9d755eb72e9014312 and renamed to frontend/src/app/user/user-purchases/user-purchase-detail/user-purchase-detail.component.spec.ts in HEAD. Version HEAD of frontend/src/app/user/user-purchases/user-purchase-detail/user-purchase-detail.component.spec.ts left in tree.

Comment: CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in frontend/src/app/user/book-detail/book-detail.component.ts
Auto-merging frontend/src/app/user/book-detail/book-detail.component.scss
Auto-merging frontend/src/app/app.module.ts
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Comment: ¿Si borro la carpeta .git de mi proyecto y creo un nuevo repositorio y subo todo el proyecto ?